Машинное обучение: выбор значения из списка возможных для каждой строки
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как называется такая технология для классификации в ML:
Например, имеются данные как на картинке, нужно чтобы модель научилась выбирать ресурс из списка, который приводится для каждой строки. Также в каждой строке есть списки с показателями по каждому ресурсу.

